# JS Object structuring and addition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

Just a question about JS object structuring. I have an object called `mainObject` I want to push values in so they appear in a format like the second section of code.  The values will be added in a loop. I want to be able to do something along the lines of:-

```
mainObject.data.push({lat : val['lat'], lng: val['lng'], count: 40});}
```

Could someone tell me how I can go about doing this? Trying  to get my head around JS objects.

```
var mainObject = {
    max: 46};

var mainObject = {
            max: 46,
            data: [{lat: 33.5363, lng:-117.044, count: 1},{lat: 33.5608, lng:-117.24, count: 1},{lat: 38, lng:-97, count: 1},{lat: 38.9358, lng:-77.1621, count: 1}]
    };
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It depends. Where are the values coming from? Array? Object?

Comment: Why do you have `var mainObject` twice? With the second one, your `push` code should work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript `.push` is reserved for arrays. To add to an object that already has a property you can simply do this.

```
var mainObject = {
    max: 46
};

mainObject.data = [{lat : val['lat'], lng: val['lng'], count: 40}];
```

You would then end up with an object that looked like this:

```
mainObject{
    max : 46,
    data : [{lat : val['lat'], lng: val['lng'], count: 40}]
}
```

Which is what you wanted.

EDIT:

@cristoph pointed out that if you change the instansiation of your initial mainObject then you could do this:

```
 var mainObject = {
     max : 46,
     data : [] 
 }

 mainObject.data.push({lat : val['lat'], lng: val['lng'], count: 40});
```

Which would give you the same result.

Either way you choose to do it, once `data` is a property of `mainObject` and is an array, you can then continue to use `.push` to insert more elements into it.

So doing this to the above:

```
 mainObject.data.push({foo : bar});
```

Would yield:

```
 mainObject{
     max : 46,
     data : [{lat : val['lat'], lng: val['lng'], count: 40}, {foo : bar}]
 }
```

Comment: push is perfectly fine if he has `mainObject{max:46,data:[]}`. So probably the only thing OP needs to change is the initialisation of the `mainObject`.

Comment: @Christoph yes if he already has the `data` property and it's value is an array. I believe that he wanted to add a new property, which you would do with the code that I presented

Comment: But what if I'm pushing multiple items?

Comment: @user1840255 see my newest update, that should answer all your questions.